# Iterate with regex in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++, loops

I have a text file like this:

```
(A) foo
(B) bar
(B) eggs
x spam
```

(A), (B) etc. are priority tags. They get changed, after which the file is sorted so that lines with prio (A) are on top. 
I'm wondering if there is a one-line regex search & replace that will replace ONLY THE FIRST tag (A), the first (B) and so on, with CR/LF [tag], so that the file looks like this:

```
(A) foo

(B) bar
(B) eggs

x spam
```

It's easy to make a script that does this. But a regex, callable as a macro in Notepad++ would be just perfect. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

Replace

```
(\([^)]*\))(.*\r\n)(?!\1)
```

with

```
\1\2\r\n
```

**Explanation:**

`[^)]*` means zero or more characters that aren't `)`.
`\([^)]*\)` - just gets something in brackets (you need to escape `(` and `)` with `\`).
Surrounded by `()` to store it in the first group (use `\1` to get it).
`.*\r\n` - anything followed by a new line.
Surrounded by `()` to store it in the second group (use `\2` to get it).
`(?!\1)` - negative look-ahead, the same tag shouldn't be on the next line.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Will look for more documentation on (negative) look-ahead. Very useful, thanks again.

Comment: @RolfBly Remember to [upvote and/or accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168143/206447) this answer if you found it helpful.